# AttributeError in pytorch

Tags: github, pytorch, neural-network

I want use
https://github.com/mmbejani/TikhonovRegularizationTerm. This library includes the implementation of regularization tikhonov terms that were published from 2010 until now (2020).

I am trying to train a very basic feed forward nn with this lib on mnist data set and getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WeightDecay' object has no attribute 'backward'
```

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.003, momentum=0.9)
time0 = time()
epochs = 15
for e in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    for images, labels in trainloader:
        # Flatten MNIST images into a 784 long vector
        images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)
    
        # Training pass
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        output = model(images)
        loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        loss_function_with_regularization = WeightDecay(model, loss_function)

        #This is where the model learns by backpropagating
        loss_function_with_regularization.backward()
        
        #And optimizes its weights here
        optimizer.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item()
    else:
        print("Epoch {} - Training loss: {}".format(e, running_loss/len(trainloader)))
print("\nTraining Time (in minutes) =",(time()-time0)/60)`
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error says is that there is no `backward` attribute on `WeightDecay` class.

Here's the definition of the class: https://github.com/mmbejani/TikhonovRegularizationTerm/blob/main/regularization.py#L11

It contains no attribute with the name `backward`. It has attribute `forward`, but no `backward`.

The class `WeightDecay` inherits from the `torch.nn.Module` class. Here's the definition for it: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L366 — it also does not include an attribute with the name `backward`.

Here's how the attributes `forward` and `backward` are usually defined: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69501410/3694363 — and I don't any similar code in https://github.com/mmbejani/TikhonovRegularizationTerm.

Either the `README` does not reflect the actual usage of the code, or pytorch has changed the API in the last two years so much that this code no longer works with current versions of it.